# Export variable via xterm and run script

Tags: bash, export, xterm

I have *.sh script and I would like send xterm with variable and run script. How do I must define this command.

script name :

> lolo.sh

variable :

> FILES2=/home/lo/plop/

My xterm:

```
xterm ; FILES2=/home/lo/plop ; export FILES2 ; lolo.sh
```

In sh script I have one line

> export FILES2

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign to the variable before running `xterm`. The variable will be exported in the shell the xterm is running:

```
files=xyz xterm -hold -e 'echo $files'
```

Comment: Thank you, but where is shell script?

TERM=xterm ; FILES2=/home/lo/plop ; export FILES2 ; lolo.sh

But it doesn't work

Comment: How do you test it?

Comment: I send it from another server to linux server, where data are...And Script didn 't start.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to export a variable through ssh?